# Update elements from a JSON array, with no key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Update 0th element CarId in @CarJaosn.
There is no key for array objects

```
 DECLARE @CarJaosn VARCHAR(MAX) = 
 '[
    {
        "CarTd": 1208,
        "HoldReasonEnum":2, 
        "Attachment": '',
        "FromDate":"2021-08-18",
        "ToDate":"2021-08-18"
    }
 ]'
```

I have try with

```
SET @CarJaosn = JSON_MODIFY(@CarJaosn, '$.[0].CarTd', 5);
```

Are there any ways to solve?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON root is an array, so instead of:

```sql
SET @CarJaosn = JSON_MODIFY(@CarJaosn, '$.[0].CarTd', 5);
```

Simply use:

```sql
SET @CarJaosn = JSON_MODIFY(@CarJaosn, '$[0].CarTd', 5);
```